# HIBERNATE4 org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm learnig Hibernate4 and I have encountered this problem while trying the XML hibernate mapping.

I'm using eclipse and MySQL.

> The error when I try to insert my object in the DB table:
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:
>   com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores

**Hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="sfBDHibernate">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdhibernate</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <mapping class="com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

You can see the class Proveedores is mapped.

**ProveedoresDAO.java:**

```
package com.hibernate.gestionproductos.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores;

public class ProveedoresDAO {

    private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
configure hay que ponerle el path
        Configuration configuracion = new Configuration().configure();
        // HIBERNATE 4
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                                    .applySettings(configuracion.getProperties());
        SessionFactory sf = configuracion.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        return sf;  
    }

    public void insertarProveedor(Proveedores prov) {
        try {
            SessionFactory sf = getSessionFactory();
            Session sesion = sf.openSession();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = sesion.beginTransaction();
            sesion.save(prov);

            tx.commit();
            sesion.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public List<Proveedores> listarProveedores() {
        try {
            SessionFactory sf = getSessionFactory();
            Session sesion = sf.openSession();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx = sesion.beginTransaction();

            List<Proveedores> lista = sesion.createCriteria(Proveedores.class).list();
            tx.commit();
            sesion.close();
            return lista;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }   
    }
}
```

**Proveedores.java:**

```
package com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo;

public class Proveedores implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long idproveedores;
    private String nombre;
    private String contacto;
    private String email;
    private String telefono;

    public Proveedores() {
    }

    public Proveedores(String nombre, String email) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Proveedores(String nombre, String contacto, String email, String telefono) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.contacto = contacto;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public Long getIdproveedores() {
        return this.idproveedores;
    }

    public void setIdproveedores(Long idproveedores) {
        this.idproveedores = idproveedores;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getContacto() {
        return this.contacto;
    }

    public void setContacto(String contacto) {
        this.contacto = contacto;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return this.telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

}
```

**Proveedores.hbm.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores" table="proveedores" catalog="bdhibernate">
        <id name="idproveedores" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="idproveedores" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nombre" type="string">
            <column name="nombre" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="contacto" type="string">
            <column name="contacto" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="telefono" type="string">
            <column name="telefono" length="12" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**ConfiguracionXML.java:**

```
package com.hibernate.gestionproductos.programa;

import java.util.List;

import com.hibernate.gestionproductos.dao.ProveedoresDAO;
import com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores;

public class ConfiguracionXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Proveedores prov = new Proveedores();
        prov.setNombre("Proveedor 3");
        prov.setContacto("Juan");
        prov.setEmail("juan@proveedor3.com");
        prov.setTelefono("632227612");

        ProveedoresDAO dao = new ProveedoresDAO();
        dao.insertarProveedor(prov);
        System.out.println("Se ha insertado el proveedor");

        List<Proveedores> proveedores = dao.listarProveedores();
        System.out.println("Listado de Proveedores:\n");
        for (Proveedores p : proveedores) {
            System.out.println(p.getIdproveedores() + " - " + p.getNombre());
        }
    }

}
```

Here at dao.insertarProveedor(prov) it breaks:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:
>   com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores Se ha insertado el
>   proveedor     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:776)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1451)
>   .....

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Hibernate.cfg.xml where you have mentioned

```
<mapping class="com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores"/>
```

This tells the Hibernate system to read this class as an entity, but the class itself doesn't has any such information. The above configuration(or **class** property of mapping tag) is used when you use annotations to describe an entity. In case you are using hbm XML to provide info about your entity, then use **resource** property of mapping tag in the following way -

```
<mapping resource="Proveedores.hbm.xml"/>
```

So replacing this line in the hbm xml doc will make Hibernate read the mapping definitions which you provided. As you didn't specify it now, you mapping info is not being read, and thus Hibernate doesn't know about this entity resulting in Unknown Entity.

Comment: I tried replacing as you suggested, with both the complete route and the short version, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok, if I add the class Proveedores programmatically:  configuracion.addClass(com.hibernate.gestionproductos.modelo.Proveedores.class); I can make it work. However that XML mapping line is not being read, I would like to know why xml Mapping is not working.

Comment: Make sure that the hbm xml is in the classpath of your application. So was the error same when you mentioned mapping resource-"...hbm.xml"?

Comment: <mapping resource="com/hibernate/gestionproductos/modelo/Proveedores.hbm.xml"/> this is the mapping. the hibernate.cfg.xml is in 'src/hibernate.cfg.xml ' package and the Proveedore.hbm.xml is in the package 'src/com/hibernate/gestionproductos/modelo/Proveedores.hbm.xml' alonside with the Proveedores.java. Yes the error was the same: Unknown entity.

Comment: @nanonymous did you get to know why your XML mapping is not picked up? I am getting the same issue.